# Reason for type error when converting date column to_datetime with pandas in a dash app?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` when my code reaches here: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')` during the rendering of the plotly graphs in the dash app.

The code below was working fine but for some reason has stopped:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from datetime import date, datetime


current_date = date.today()


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///seizure.db')
df = pd.read_sql("Seizures", engine)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date
frequency_count = df.groupby(['date'])['seizure_type'].value_counts().to_frame(name='frequency').reset_index



def create_dash_application(flask_app):

    # Styles
    DATEPICKER_STYLE = {
        'padding': "10px",
        'margin': "10px",
        'margin-left': "50px",
    }

    FIGS = {
        'border-radius': '25px',
        'border': '2px solid #ccc',
        'padding': "10px",
        'margin': "10px",
        'box-shadow': '0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)',

    }

    TOTALS = {
        'border-radius': '25px',
        'border': '2px solid #ccc',
        'padding': "10px",
        'padding-top': "20px",
        'margin': "10px",
        'margin-top': "20px",
        'box-shadow': '0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)',
        'justify-content': 'center',
        'align-items': 'center',

    }

    #Components
    dash_app = dash.Dash(
        server=flask_app, name='Dashboard', url_base_pathname='/dashboard/',
        external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
        meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport',
                    'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}]
    )

    navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
        children=[
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("New Entry", href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/new-entry")),
            dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Calendar", href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/calendar")),
        ],
        brand="Dashboard",
        color="primary",
        dark=True,
    )

    totals = html.Div(
        [
            dbc.Alert([html.H1("Total Number of Seizures Per Period: ")], color="light", 
            id="totals_div")
        ],

    )

    download = html.Div(
        [
            dbc.Alert([html.H1("EXPORT")], color="light")
        ],

    )

    # App Layout: Bootstrap

    dash_app.layout = dbc.Container([
        dbc.Row([navbar]),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id='my-date-picker-range',
                    end_date_placeholder_text="End Date",
                    min_date_allowed=date(2000, 1, 1),
                    max_date_allowed=date(2100, 1, 1),
                    initial_visible_month=current_date,
                ),
            ], style=DATEPICKER_STYLE, width={'size': 3})
        ], justify='start'),

        dbc.Row([

            dbc.Col([
                dcc.Graph(id="frequency_fig")
            ], style=FIGS, xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5),


            dbc.Col([
                dcc.Graph(id="pie_fig"),
            ], style=FIGS, xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5)

        ], justify='around'),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                totals
            ], style=TOTALS, xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5),
            dbc.Col([
                download
            ], style=TOTALS, xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5),
        ], justify='around'),
    ])

    @dash_app.callback(
        Output('frequency_fig', 'figure'),
        [Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
         Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date')]
    )
    def f_figupdate(start_date, end_date):
        df = frequency_count
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
        df = df[(df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] < end_date)]
        f_fig = px.bar(df,
                       x='date',
                       y='frequency',
                       color='seizure_type',
                       title="Frequency of Seizures")

        f_fig.update_layout(xaxis_title='Days of the Month',
                            yaxis_title='Number of seizures')
        return f_fig

    @dash_app.callback(
        Output('pie_fig', 'figure'),
        [Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
         Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date')]
    )
    def p_figupdate(start_date, end_date):
        df = frequency_count
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
        df = df[(df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] < end_date)]
        seizure_type_count = df.seizure_type.value_counts()

        p_fig = px.pie(df,
                       labels=seizure_type_count.index,
                       values=seizure_type_count.values,
                       title="Percentage of Seizures by Type",
                       names=seizure_type_count.index,
                       hole=0.4,
                       )

        p_fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textfont_size=15, textinfo='percent')

        return p_fig

    return dash_app
```

Comment: Include a sample of `df` using `df.head().to_dict()` for example.

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: Well there you go. You don't have a valid dataframe so you can't really be doing anything to it. Check the documentation of [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) and see if you're using it correctly. It doesn't seem to accept an "engine" argument.

Comment: Sorry, this was for the df in the p_figureupdate function. The the original df is valid and produces: {'id': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9}, 'date': {0: datetime.date(2021, 10, 2), 1: datetime.date(2021, 10, 2), 2: datetime.date(2021, 10, 3), 3: datetime.date(2021, 10, 6), 4: datetime.date(2021, 10, 7)}, 'seizure_type': {0: 'Medium', 1: 'Medium', 2: 'Strong', 3: 'Strong', 4: 'Strong'}, 'note': {0: 'Wet', 1: '', 2: '', 3: 'Been brewing all day', 4: ''}}

Comment: Ah - you have two lines that do `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])`. Before the line that's causing your error, you use `frequency_count`. What is that?

Comment: I was trying to create a new dataframe using this method: 
frequency_count = df.groupby(['date'])['seizure_type'].value_counts().to_frame(name='frequency').reset_index

Comment: Ahhh. You need to do `reset_index()` i.e., use the brackets and *call* the function. Otherwise you're simply *assigning* the function to `frequency_count`

Comment: Oh my god. I must have deleted them by accident at some point. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Haha, happens. Easy to overlook small issues in such a huge chunk of code. Happy to help!